# how to pass an xml file to lxml to parse?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to parse an xml file using lxml. xml.etree allowed me to simply pass the file name as a parameter to the `parse` function, so I attempted to do the same with lxml.

My code:

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml import objectify

file = "C:\Projects\python\cb.xml"
tree = etree.parse(file)
```

but I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cb.py", line 5, in <module>
    tree = etree.parse(file)
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2698, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:4
9590)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1491, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etre
e.c:71205)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1520, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src/lxml/lx
ml.etree.c:71488)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1420, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile (src/lxml/lxml.e
tree.c:70583)
  File "parser.pxi", line 975, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile (src/
lxml/lxml.etree.c:67736)
  File "parser.pxi", line 539, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDo
c (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63820)
  File "parser.pxi", line 625, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.e
tree.c:64741)
  File "parser.pxi", line 565, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etr
ee.c:64084)
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: AttValue: " or ' expected, line 2, column 26
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As said in accepted answer, nothing is wrong with `lxml` here, so downvoting the question. Maybe a rename of the question's title would avoid wrong search for problems on this module.

Comment: @Joel - My question title doesn't imply that there's anything wrong with `lxml` - only that there may be something wrong with the way I am passing the file to lxml to parse. If you can suggest an alternate title then I'll be happy to oblige (it's not clear from your comment what you think i should change it to).

Comment: Hum. Weird, I can now see nothing wrong with the title :/ So maybe I missed the correct question, and wrongly ticked yours down! And, I cannot remove the downvote without you editing the question. If you do a little edit to unlock it, I'd be pleased to correct my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is (1) not checking whether you got the same outcome by using `xml.etree` on the same file (2) not reading the error message, which indicates a syntax error in line 2 of the file, way down stream from any file-opening issue

Comment: John, what do you mean by "same outcome", same outcome as what?

Comment: same outcome as with lxml, thus ruling out lxml as the problem

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across a similar error message this morning, and for me the answer was a malformed DTD. In my DTD, there was an Attribute definition with a default value that was not enclosed in quotes - as soon as I changed that, the error didn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your *XML Markup*. You aren't doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

lxml allows you load a broken xml by creating a parser instance with [recover=True](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html)

```
etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
```

While this is not ideal, I use this to load an xml for schema/dtd/schematron validation.